# best way to run a php script away from the template?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

I'm looking for some inspiration on the best way to run a php script away from the template. I know that the wordpress core files won't have loaded, so I am wondering what workgflow you follow when doing this?

cheers

Comment: What do you mean by **away from the template**?

Comment: I mean running a script that is inapproprate to run on the current template file. i.e, I need to sent get variables that can't be loaded on to the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@Mild Fuzz:**

Sounds like what you might be looking for is **the `template_redirect` hook**.  If you add a function for that hook then you can output whatever you want and end with an `exit;` statement.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yoursite_template_redirect' );
function yoursite_template_redirect() {
  if (isset($_GET['foo']) && $_GET['foo']=='bar') {
    // Do whatever you want when $_GET['foo']=='bar'
  }
}
```

You'll need to figure out what criteria to test for such as I showed with `$_GET['foo']=='bar'`, but is that what you are looking for?

Comment: not 100% on when this will action, could you expand?

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - Have you tried it yet? If yes, what did it do or not that you didn't want or did want?